# How does an AO2 station see distant lightning when fogged in?

Tags: lightning

From local aerodrome weather this morning:

> SPECI KCRQ 161448Z 19007KT 1/2SM R24/3500VP6000FT FG OVC003 20/18
> A2994 RMK AO2 LTG DSNT SW AND W

How does an AO2 station observe for reporting, distant lightning when the station is ensconced in low visibility fog?  The lightning and high-based cumulus actually was there at that time, but how would the reporting station "see" it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a network of lightning sensors which detect lightning strikes. You can see this information, for example, on various weather-radar apps. The network feeds back to the automated weather station and allows the AWOS/ASOS to display lightning information.

From [the AIM 7–1–10**d**:](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap7_section_1.html)

> **2. Every ASOS/AWOS will contain the following basic set of sensors:**
> **(i)** Automated Lightning Detection and Reporting System (ALDARS) (excluding Alaska and Pacific Island sites).

High-level information on ALDARS can be found, for example, in [this brochure from the FAA William J. Hughes Technical Center](https://www.tc.faa.gov/its/cmd/visitors/data/ACT-300/aldars.pdf) and [this column from Flying Magazine](https://www.flyingmag.com/does-asos-have-a-built-in-lightning-detection/).

As for how the detectors themselves actually work: some may indeed use optical sensors, but most use antennas to detect the burst of radio frequency energy caused by lightning. NOAA's [National Severe Storms Laboratory](https://www.nssl.noaa.gov/education/svrwx101/lightning/detection/) and [SciJinks](https://scijinks.gov/lightning-detection/) websites contain more information on detection systems; the Wikipedia article on [lightning detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_detection) would be another starting point for more research.

Comment: [Related question: How far does the lightning detector work at an AWOS station, as reported in a METAR?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/90607/54557)